# Why does my blockquote look like this on wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

http://www.thepcmasterrace.com/forums/?mingleforumaction=viewtopic&t=8.0#postid-21

Why does this happen when I try to post via blockquote.

```
<div class="cosmo-blockquote "><p>

Quote from admin on June 25, 2015, 23:47
test</p></div>asdf
```

Comment: because it's escaped by the code, what forum software do you use?

Comment: I'm using Mingle Forums the theme I'm using for some reason cause this to happen and block quote and youtube embed not to work.